# Jira , How to check if a ticket has been created from email or manually

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am using a jira mail handler to automatically create tickets whenever email comes to a particular mail id. However many of the users who are sending mails are part of jira users and jira will create the issue with creator as their name. Later looking at the tickets is there any way to identify whether the ticket was created from email or the user manually created it. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean to be able to filter them with JQL ??

Comment: No. Not to filter by JQL. In a project tickets will be created in two ways. 1. via emails using mail handler 2. People who have create issue permission can create the ticket manually also. How I will identify whether a ticket is created from email or user manually created it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is not possible automatically. What about using a extra customfield? this way you can fill that new field, with the value you want: one for manually opened tickets, and another for email opened tickets. You can show or hide this field, and this would allow you to look for manually opened using jql (even it is not your first need :) )

For making it more visual, then you can use a bit of proggramatic magic and represent the values with icons or wahtever.

Let me know if it is not clear or if you need help for adding the new field or whatever.

Edit: the easiest way for doing this could be add to every issues opened by mail, at the begining of the summary something like "from mail:" and then the real summary. Anyway probably better if you customize the handler or create new one

Regards

Comment: Thanks. I am on jira cloud and only the basic email handler is available. Not sure how I can update the custom field from this.

Comment: I have modified the answer